# Excel Export getting error: Failed - Network Error on large exports

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to export tables off of a web page.
This snippet of code works fine when I export tables of < 1000 rows or so, but when I try to export larger tables I get the error: Failed Network Error.  This happens in chrome.  It doesn't do anything in IE (surprise).

Is it a memory issue?  Any ideas how I can export large tables without running into issues?

Thanks for any help

```
    var dt = new Date();
    var day = dt.getDate();
    var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = dt.getFullYear();
    var hour = dt.getHours();
    var mins = dt.getMinutes();
    var postfix = month + "." + day + "." + year + "_" + hour + "." + mins;
    //creating a temporary HTML link element (they support setting file names)
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    //getting data from our div that contains the HTML table
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table_div = document.getElementById('datatable');
    var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
    //setting the file name
    a.download = 'MachineReport_' + postfix + '.xls';
    //triggering the function
    a.click();
    //just in case, prevent default behaviour
    e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers, but after research it seems to be part of the 2meg limit Chrome imposes when trying to execute this script.  I do not know of a work around.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same problem. This help me solved it. Please try replace:

```
 a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
```

With:

```
xData = new Blob([table_html], { type: 'text/csv' });
var xUrl = URL.createObjectURL(xData);
a.href = xUrl;
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, please @spas2k select it as correct answer.